# Option:selected in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to do the following in javascript:

```
document.querySelector('select[name="plan_type"] option')
```

However, how would I get the selected option? For example:

```
document.querySelector('select[name="plan_type"] option:selected')
```

(the equivalent in jquery would be: `$('select[name="plan_type"] option:selected')`.

Comment: I thought one of the main features of jQuery was compatibility with CSS3 psuedo-selectors - not sure if vanilla JS has direct access (I could be wrong - someone lemme know if I am :))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can obtain a reference to this type of element using its name:

```
oSelectOne = oForm.elements["select_one_element_name"];
```

To get the index of the selected option in the JavaScript options array of the select element, we can use the selectedIndex property of the select element object

```
var e =document.querySelector('select[name="plan_type"]');
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
```

We can now use this index to determine the value of the selected option:

```
var strUser_value = e.options[index].value;
```

If we needed to get the text corresponding to the selected option, we would need to use the text property of the option element, instead of the value property:

```
var strUser_text = e.options[index].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

QuerySelector is meant to use `css` selectors on the DOM, similar to jQuery, but they don't support the pseudo selectors, [read on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Usage_notes)

What you can do is to take a two step approach, get the element and then get the value from that element.

Like this:

```
var myElement = document.querySelector('select[name="plan_type"]);
var myValue = myElement.querySelector('[selected]').value;
```

Other general way to do this without query selector (needs id for the element), (name would do too)

```
var e = document.getElementById("{id_goes_here}");
var selectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The options collection returns a collection of all  elements in a drop-down list. Using the property selectedIndex to get the selected option.

```
let options = document.querySelector('select').options;
let text = options[options.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.